# Any alternative way to compute IntegerPartitions?

Tags: combinatorics, partitions

I tried to compute IntegerPartitions[100] using mathematica on my intel core i3 system. the system hangsup everytime. Is there another way to do such a large computation?

Comment: Assume it is possible. What would you do with this result? Will it be in some ways useful?

Comment: s I need to compute a frequency plot of each number across all partitions of n. e.g freq of occurrence of 1, 2,3,4 and 5 across all partitions of 5

Comment: It might be possible to do it. Can you please provide an illustration of what kind of frequency plot are you expecting for, say 20, instead 100?

Comment: It is what you are looking for `IntegerPartitions[5] // Flatten // Histogram`?

Comment: what other visualisations apart from histogram can i obtain?

Answer (score 12):

There are 190,569,292 unrestricted integer partitions of 100 (`PartitionsP@100`).

This will need >1gb of RAM just to keep the final result.

You can generate them in blocks, e.g., partitions 3000000-3000010:

```
IntegerPartitions[100, All, All, {3000000, 3000010}]
```

In any case, you'll be looking at a long computation.

However, if you're just after the tally of the members of the unrestricted partitions (that's my interpretation based on OP and responses to comments), this will be quite snappy (e.g., takes a few hundredths of a second for tally of partitions of 100 on an ancient netbook) - returns results as would `Sort@Tally@Flatten@IntegerPartitions[...]`, use results as desired for visualization:

```
partTally[m_] := Module[{t},
  t[n_, n_] = 1;
  t[n_, k_] /; k < n := t[n, k] = t[n - k, k] + PartitionsP[n - k]; 
  t[_, _] = 0;
  Table[{z, t[m, z]}, {z, 1, m}]];
```

Usage example:

```
result=partTally[100];
Short[result]
ListPlot[result, PlotRange -> All, InterpolationOrder -> 0, Joined -> True];
```

> {{1, 1452423276}, {2, 681391671}, {3, 425625071}, <<94>>, {98,    2},
>   {99, 1}, {100, 1}}

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You may use `PartitionsP` to skip calculating the partitions. This will improve performance *"infinity-fold"* (in practical terms) for the integer frequency counts on larger numbers.

```
ClearAll[integerPartitionFrequency];
integerPartitionFrequency[number_Integer, int_Integer] := 
 Total@PartitionsP[Range[number - int, 0, -int]]
```

Then compare

```
KeySort@Counts@Flatten@IntegerPartitions[10]
(* <|1 -> 97, 2 -> 41, 3 -> 21, 4 -> 13, 5 -> 8, 6 -> 5, 7 -> 3, 8 -> 2, 9 -> 1, 10 -> 1|> *)
```

and

```
Association @@ Function[{num}, (# -> integerPartitionFrequency[num, #] & /@ Range[num])][10]
(* <|1 -> 97, 2 -> 41, 3 -> 21, 4 -> 13, 5 -> 8, 6 -> 5, 7 -> 3, 8 -> 2, 9 -> 1, 10 -> 1|> *)
```

`integerPartitionFrequency` makes use of the partitions being combinations instead of permutations.  It calculates the number of partitions of `number` with `int` in position 1 (leaving `number- int` to partition), then with `int` in position 1 and 2 (leaving `number- 2 int` to partition), then with `int` in position 1, 2, and 3 (leaving `number- 3 int` to partition), and so on while  $\text{number} - n  \text{int} \geq 0$.  Then it `Total`s these counts.

Take `number = 4` and `int = 2`.  Then

- 2 in position 1 -> `PartitionsP[number - int] == PartitionsP[2] == 2`
- 2 in position 1 and 2 -> `PartitionsP[number - 2 int] == PartitionsP[0] == 1`

Giving a frequency of 3 for `int = 2`.  This matches with the number of `2`'s in `IntergerPartitions[4]`.  Since `PartitionsP` threads over lists then `Range` is used to produce the list of $\text{number} - n  \text{int}$ values.

Now for `100`this returns immediately.

```
Association @@ 
 Function[{num}, (# -> integerPartitionFrequency[num, #] & /@ 
     Range[num])][100]
(*
<|1 -> 1452423276, 2 -> 681391671, 3 -> 425625071, 4 -> 298674842, 
 5 -> 223239954, 6 -> 173559786, 7 -> 138586227, 8 -> 112799928, 
 9 -> 93128655, 10 -> 77732922, 11 -> 65437378, 12 -> 55461711, 
 13 -> 47261866, 14 -> 40451977, 15 -> 34745939, 16 -> 29931593, 
 17 -> 25844039, 18 -> 22357203, 19 -> 19369326, 20 -> 16800909, 
 21 -> 14585738, 22 -> 12671374, 23 -> 11012882, 24 -> 9574403, 
 25 -> 8324449, 26 -> 7237775, 27 -> 6291737, 28 -> 5468189, 
 29 -> 4750480, 30 -> 4125348, 31 -> 3580375, 32 -> 3105717, 
 33 -> 2692000, 34 -> 2331869, 35 -> 2018162, 36 -> 1745348, 
 37 -> 1507935, 38 -> 1301731, 39 -> 1122507, 40 -> 967094, 
 41 -> 832205, 42 -> 715451, 43 -> 614289, 44 -> 526900, 45 -> 451318,
  46 -> 386177, 47 -> 329942, 48 -> 281594, 49 -> 239945, 
 50 -> 204227, 51 -> 173525, 52 -> 147273, 53 -> 124754, 54 -> 105558,
  55 -> 89134, 56 -> 75175, 57 -> 63261, 58 -> 53174, 59 -> 44583, 
 60 -> 37338, 61 -> 31185, 62 -> 26015, 63 -> 21637, 64 -> 17977, 
 65 -> 14883, 66 -> 12310, 67 -> 10143, 68 -> 8349, 69 -> 6842, 
 70 -> 5604, 71 -> 4565, 72 -> 3718, 73 -> 3010, 74 -> 2436, 
 75 -> 1958, 76 -> 1575, 77 -> 1255, 78 -> 1002, 79 -> 792, 80 -> 627,
  81 -> 490, 82 -> 385, 83 -> 297, 84 -> 231, 85 -> 176, 86 -> 135, 
 87 -> 101, 88 -> 77, 89 -> 56, 90 -> 42, 91 -> 30, 92 -> 22, 
 93 -> 15, 94 -> 11, 95 -> 7, 96 -> 5, 97 -> 3, 98 -> 2, 99 -> 1, 
 100 -> 1|>
*)
```

These can be directly plotted several ways. For example with `ListPlot`.

```
ListPlot[integerPartitionFrequency[100, #] & /@ Range[100], 
 Filling -> Axis, ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1. Would you care to briefly explain the math behind this?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Added explanation to the post.

Comment: now how do i plot this data?

Comment: @Ramprashanth See update.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a combination of @ciao's suggesting and @yarchik's comment:

```
assoc = <||>; max = 70; step = 10000;
Do[assoc =
   Merge[
    {assoc, 
     Counts[Flatten[
       IntegerPartitions[max, All, 
        All, {n, Min[n + step - 1, PartitionsP[max]]}]]]}, Total],
  {n, 1, PartitionsP[max], step}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* 66 seconds *)
DiscretePlot[assoc[x], {x, 1, 70}]
```

> [image]

Be aware, that `PartitionsP[70] ~= 4 000 000`. So for `max == 100` the computation should take at least an hour (on my machine). I'm near confident, that there's an analytical solution.